# ./yiic migrate command is not working yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to run the command `./yiic` migrate in `/protected` folder of but it is not showing any response.

I have checked all the configuration file including `/config/main.php`
and other files. They are correctly configured.

Could any body help me to figure it out why it is happening.

Comment: yiic requires config/console.php instead of config/main.php

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the yiic.php to execute commands, following is how you can use it:

```
path/to/php protected/yiic.php migrate
```

If you use xampp then your php path will /xampp/php/php, so you can use:

```
../../php/php protected/yiic.php migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

It's was most helpfull for me:

1.Open your root project directory

2.There should be present framework and {projectName} directories

3.Use next command:

```
php path/to/project/protected/yiic.php migrate
```

Comment: Welcome to stack oveflow. Please mind to add at least a little explanation along with your code when replying to a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you install yii successfully

For linux use:

```
php yii migrate
```

For windows use:

```
yii migrate
```